# Summation together

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have the terms:

```
Sum[
C51[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kx[pp]*kz[rr]*Ux[pp, qq, rr]
, {pp, -∞, ∞}
, {qq, -∞, ∞}
, {rr, -∞, ∞}
] + 
 Sum[
 C56[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*ky[qq]*kz[rr]*Ux[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ] + 
 Sum[
 C65[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*ky[qq]*kz[rr]*Ux[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ] + 
 Sum[
 C55[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kz[rr]^2*Ux[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ] - 
 ω^2*Sum[
 Rho[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*Ux[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ] - 
 (2*Pi*Sum[
 (p - pp)*C16[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kx[pp]*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ])/Λx - 
 (2*Pi*Sum[
 (r - rr)*C56[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kx[pp]*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ])/Λz - 
 (2*Pi*Sum[
 (q - qq)*C66[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kx[pp]*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ])/Λy + 
 Sum[
 C16[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*kx[pp]^2*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ] - 
 (2*Pi*Sum[
 (p - pp)*C12[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*ky[qq]*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ])/Λx - 
 (2*Pi*Sum[
 (r - rr)*C52[p - pp, q - qq, r - rr]*ky[qq]*Uy[pp, qq, rr]
 , {pp, -∞, ∞}
 , {qq, -∞, ∞}
 , {rr, -∞, ∞}
 ])/Λz
```

This is just an example, but in reality I have large number of terms.

**I would like to define a rule that group the coefficient of $Ux$ in one summation and the coefficient of $Uy$ in another summation.**

The rule should be applicable to large number of terms.

Comment: You need to put some effort on making your code readable, it must be properly [formatted](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4) (you did that well), but also be a **minimal working example**,  in `InputForm`, and hopefully well indented. I did that for you this time (you should check I didn't butcher your code), but next time I would just vote to close it for unreadable.

Comment: @rhermans thanks

Comment: Each of multiple terms is a triple sum over an infinite number of terms?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No there are terms that are free of summation. Thanks David